# Wire up many events that have the same event name but different namespaces

Tags: jquery

Let's say I have the following contrived code:

```
function runTriggers() {
    $(document).trigger('mytrigger.ns1');
    $(document).trigger('mytrigger.ns2');
    $(document).trigger('mytrigger.ns3');
    ...
}
```

How can I wire up one event handler to listen for simply `mytrigger` and not have to worry about mentioning every single type of namespaced trigger that may appear in the future?

I've [tried](http://jsfiddle.net/edelman/C5VTv/)

```
$(document).on('mytrigger', doSomething);
```

but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation for Namespaced Events](http://docs.jquery.com/Namespaced_Events):

```
$('.class').bind('click.namespace', function(){}); 
$('.class').trigger('click.namespace'); // Will trigger
$('.class').trigger('click');           // Will trigger
$('.class').trigger('click.other');     // Won't trigger
```

So your contrived code definitely won't work, but you can reverse the logic as follows :

```
$(document).on('mytrigger.ns1', doSomething1);
$(document).on('mytrigger.ns2', doSomething2);
$(document).on('mytrigger.ns3', doSomething3);
```

Then:

```
function runTriggers() {
    $(document).trigger('mytrigger'); // will trigger all three `doSomething` handlers.
    ...
}
```

Comment: i'm trying to do one event handler for many triggers, not one trigger.

Comment: In that case, you seem to be describing the simple case where the event is not namespaced, `$(document).on('myEvent', doSomething);`, and is triggered with `$(document).trigger('myEvent')`. One thing is certain, you can't trigger namespaced events that don't exist!

Comment: no, i'm trying to do what i'm doing in the example. basically i have many objects that trigger a namespaced `bound` custom event. i have one master object that reacts every time the `bound` event is called, but i would just like to do something like `.on('bound', handleBound)` instead of `.on('bound.xyz bound.abc bound.efg bound.etc', handleBound)`

Comment: I would need to see a real world problem to penetrate this issue;

Comment: here's a rather contrived, but more fleshed out demo of what i'm trying to do: http://jsfiddle.net/edelman/HjL8r/

Comment: I'm starting to wonder if you are trying to describe an observer (pub/sub) pattern. If so, then [this article](http://addyosmani.com/blog/jquery-1-7s-callbacks-feature-demystified/) is well worth a read.

Comment: i'm definitely trying to describe pubsub. i'm just highlighting a technical difficulty i'm having wrapping up the same event from different modules while maintaining namespacing. it would be _awesome_ if i could wrap up all events of the same type but also have granular control based on namespace. maybe even run a switch statement inside my handler based on namespace.

Comment: OK, if you are after a pub/sub design then, as far as I can tell, your problem would involve multiple publishers and a single subscriber. Don't try to address it with event namespacing. Instead, use jQuery `Callbacks` in the way described in the article referenced above, or similar.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a workaround to allow you to get close. First, you add a method to the string prototype:

```
String.prototype.namespaces = function () {
    var eventName = this + ".";
    var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
    return eventName + args.join(" " + eventName);
}
```

Then you can can bind to multiple namespaces for the same event using the `.namespaces(namespace1, namespace2...)` notation:

```
$(function () {

   $("#mydiv").on("someevent".namespaces("a","b"), function() {
       alert("hello"); 
    });

   $("#mydiv").trigger("someevent.a");
   $("#mydiv").trigger("someevent.b");     
});
```

​Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XuTrJ/1/).

Comment: clever, but i'm pretty sure i would be dragged into the street and shot for modifying the `String` prototype

Comment: @Jason lol - makes the syntax look nice but you would likely be safer making it a local utility function :p